# Setting View controls according to the Orientation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, user-interface, orientation

i created a view based application. All UI control's i created  thorough code.But view changing according to the Orientation.can i have any properties to avoid this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the following function on your FILENAMEviewcontrol.m of your project.

- -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) );
  }

Change UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait according to your orientation

if you have deleted all the commented tags, then add this.